# d3 tooltip - add div for a tooltip in d3 line chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to get the tooltip to show near the mouse pointer, but it always points to the top of the graph. What's the mistake? Is it the wrong addition of the div? 
Additionaly the tooltip does not change even if I alter the x and y positions using the left and top attributes in the style tag.

Can somebody  help ?

```
   <html>
        <head>
            <title>Kaplan Meier</title>
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.8/d3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
            <style>
                body{
                    font-family:'Ubuntu', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
                    margin:20px auto;
                    width:808px;
                }
                .my-tooltip{
                    font: bold;

                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

            <script>
                /* Globals */
                var w = 900, h = 520, m = 35, max = min = 0;
                /* Data Given */
data = {
                treatments: [// Order matters | data.treatments[a][i].t is always less than data.treatments[a][i+1].t
                    [
                        //concurrent therapy
                        {t: 0, d: 0, n: 20},
                        {t: 11.267, d: 1, n: 20},
                        {t: 31.2, d: 1, n: 19},
                        {t: 33.167, d: 0, n: 18},
                        {t: 33.367, d: 1, n: 17},
                        {t: 35.667, d: 1, n: 16},
                        {t: 39.033, d: 0, n: 15},
                        {t: 39.3, d: 1, n: 14},
                        {t: 40.067, d: 1, n: 13},
                        {t: 53.867, d: 0, n: 12},
                        {t: 56.7, d: 1, n: 11},
                        {t: 56.9, d: 0, n: 10},
                        {t: 57.7, d: 1, n: 9},
                        {t: 59.4, d: 1, n: 8},
                        {t: 71.3, d: 1, n: 7},
                        {t: 73.333, d: 1, n: 6},
                        {t: 81.967, d: 0, n: 5},
                        {t: 82.367, d: 0, n: 4},
                        {t: 84.867, d: 0, n: 3},
                        {t: 98.667, d: 0, n: 2},
                        {t: 125.9, d: 0, n: 1}
                    ],
                    [
                        //induction therapy
                        {t: 0, d: 0, n: 6},
                        {t: 5.767, d: 1, n: 6},
                        {t: 60.733, d: 0, n: 5},
                        {t: 105.9, d: 1, n: 4},
                        {t: 110.067, d: 1, n: 3},
                        {t: 117.367, d: 1, n: 2},
                        {t: 287.967, d: 0, n: 1}
                    ],
                    [
                        //induction + chemo
                        {t: 0, d: 0, n: 11},
                        {t: 12.7, d: 1, n: 11},
                        {t: 15.4667, d: 1, n: 10},
                        {t: 18.8667, d: 1, n: 9},
                        {t: 33.5333, d: 0, n: 8},
                        {t: 35.4333, d: 0, n: 6},
                        {t: 45.2333, d: 1, n: 5},
                        {t: 48.4333, d: 1, n: 4},
                        {t: 48.8333, d: 0, n: 3},
                        {t: 49.6333, d: 1, n: 2},
                        {t: 66.9667, d: 0, n: 1}
                    ],
                    [
                        //no Chemo
                        {t: 0, d: 0, n: 59},
                        {t: 5.7, d: 1, n: 59},
                        {t: 6.533, d: 1, n: 58},
                        {t: 7.2, d: 1, n: 57},
                        {t: 8.7, d: 1, n: 56},
                        {t: 10.267, d: 0, n: 55},
                        {t: 10.533, d: 0, n: 54},
                        {t: 11.9, d: 1, n: 53},
                        {t: 12.167, d: 1, n: 52},
                        {t: 12.467, d: 0, n: 51},
                        {t: 12.9, d: 1, n: 50},
                        {t: 13.1, d: 1, n: 49},
                        {t: 15.1, d: 1, n: 48},
                        {t: 15.167, d: 1, n: 47},
                        {t: 16.2, d: 1, n: 46},
                        {t: 17.167, d: 1, n: 45},
                        {t: 19.8, d: 1, n: 44},
                        {t: 20.433, d: 1, n: 43},
                        {t: 21, d: 1, n: 42},
                        {t: 22.3, d: 1, n: 41},
                        {t: 26.167, d: 1, n: 40},
                        {t: 26.6, d: 1, n: 39},
                        {t: 28.1, d: 1, n: 38},
                        {t: 29.8, d: 1, n: 37},
                        {t: 30.6, d: 1, n: 36},
                        {t: 31.033, d: 1, n: 35},
                        {t: 32.4, d: 1, n: 34},
                        {t: 32.433, d: 1, n: 33},
                        {t: 32.633, d: 1, n: 32},
                        {t: 36.367, d: 1, n: 31},
                        {t: 38.967, d: 1, n: 30},
                        {t: 41.467, d: 1, n: 29},
                        {t: 42.833, d: 1, n: 28},
                        {t: 44.667, d: 1, n: 27},
                        {t: 44.833, d: 1, n: 26},
                        {t: 47.667, d: 0, n: 25},
                        {t: 50.333, d: 1, n: 24},
                        {t: 50.633, d: 1, n: 23},
                        {t: 55.533, d: 1, n: 22},
                        {t: 57.7, d: 1, n: 21},
                        {t: 61.833, d: 1, n: 20},
                        {t: 63.367, d: 1, n: 19},
                        {t: 66.667, d: 1, n: 18},
                        {t: 78.633, d: 1, n: 17},
                        {t: 85.467, d: 1, n: 16},
                        {t: 85.967, d: 1, n: 15},
                        {t: 98.267, d: 1, n: 14},
                        {t: 105.867, d: 0, n: 13},
                        {t: 109.4, d: 1, n: 12},
                        {t: 116.2, d: 0, n: 11},
                        {t: 116.267, d: 1, n: 10},
                        {t: 136.133, d: 0, n: 9},
                        {t: 151.667, d: 1, n: 8},
                        {t: 152.1, d: 0, n: 7},
                        {t: 167.367, d: 1, n: 6},
                        {t: 192.5, d: 1, n: 5},
                        {t: 193.8, d: 1, n: 4},
                        {t: 195.6, d: 0, n: 3},
                        {t: 241.967, d: 1, n: 2},
                        {t: 279.1, d: 1, n: 1}]

                ]};
                /* Computed Data progression, survival, prob, censored */
                for (var a = 0; a < data.treatments.length; a++) {
                    for (var b = 0; b < data.treatments[a].length; b++) {
                        var reed = data.treatments[a][b];
                        var brad = (b > 0) ? data.treatments[a][b - 1].n - reed.d : reed.n;
                        reed.progression = reed.d / reed.n;
                        reed.survival = 1 - reed.progression;
                        reed.prob = (b == 0) ? reed.survival : data.treatments[a][b - 1].prob * reed.survival;
                        max = (max < reed.t) ? reed.t : max;
                        reed.censored = (reed.n < brad) ? true : false;
                    }
                }
                console.log(data);
                /* Begin d3.js */
                //Scalar functions
                var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, max]).range([0, w - m * 2]);
                var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([1, 0]).range([0, h - m]);
                //Define axses
                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(x)
                        .tickSize(2)
                        .tickPadding(6)
                        .orient("bottom");
                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(y)
                        .tickSize(2)
                        .tickPadding(6)
                        .orient("left");
                //This is the accessor function
                var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                        .x(function (d) {
                            return x(d.t) + 2 * m;
                        })
                        .y(function (d) {
                            return y(d.prob);
                        })
                        .interpolate("step-before");
                var tip = d3.tip()
                        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
                        .offset([x, y]);

                var div = d3.select("body")
                                    .append("div")
                                    .attr("class", "toopltip");
                //Draw the svg container
                var kaplan = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w + (2 * m))
                        .attr("height", h + (4 * m));
                kaplan.call(tip);


                //Draw the lines
                var redLine = kaplan.append("path")
                        .attr("d", lineFunction(data.treatments[0]))
                        .attr("stroke", "#ff4c4c")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
                        .attr("fill", "none")
                        .attr("opacity", 0.7)
                        .on('mouseover', function () {
                            d3.select(this)                          //on mouseover of each line, give it a nice thick stroke
                                    .style("stroke-width", '6px');

                            div.transition()
                                    .duration(200)
                                    .style("opacity", 0.8);
                            div.html("<strong> Months Survived : " + d3.format(".2f")(x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0])) + " Probability of Survival : " + y.invert(d3.format(".2f")(d3.mouse(this)[1])))
                                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 200) + "px")
                                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 500) + "px");
                        })
                        .on('mouseout', function () {
                            d3.select(this).style("stroke-width", "3px");
                            div.transition()
                                    .duration(500)
                                    .style("opacity", 0);
                        });
                var blueLine = kaplan.append("path")
                        .attr("d", lineFunction(data.treatments[1]))
                        .attr("stroke", "#197319")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
                        .attr("fill", "none")
                        .attr("opacity", 0.7);
                var thirdLine = kaplan.append("path")
                        .attr("d", lineFunction(data.treatments[2]))
                        .attr("stroke", "#6666ff")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
                        .attr("fill", "none")
                        .attr("opacity", 0.7);
                var fourthLine = kaplan.append("path")
                        .attr("d", lineFunction(data.treatments[3]))
                        .attr("stroke", "#ffc04c")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
                        .attr("fill", "none")
                        .attr("opacity", 0.7);

                //Draw the x-axis
                var theXAxis = kaplan.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "xaxis")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 2 * m + "," + h + ")")
                        .call(xAxis)
                        .append("text")
                        .text("Overall Survival (in months)");
                //Draw the y-axis
                var theYAxis = kaplan.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "yaxis")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 1.75 * m + ", " + m + ")")
                        .call(yAxis)
                        .append("text")
                        .attr('text-anchor', 'bottom')
                        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
                        .text("Survival Rate");
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tooltip `<div>` needs its `position` attribute to be `absolute` for `left` and `top` to have any effect:

```
d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("position", "absolute")
```

After changing this, the tooltip position can simply be set to the mouse position:

```
.style("left", d3.event.pageX)
.style("top", d3.event.pageY)
```

Here is [an example](http://jsbin.com/tadipo).

(Also, you spelled "tooltip" wrong, originally)